# How to save variables after quitting and reopening in AppleScript?

Tags: variables, properties, applescript

I am writing a very complicated AppleScript application that requires variables to be saved after quitting. So if I set the variable while it is running, close it, reopen it the variable will still be the same.

This script is intended to bring up a setup menu on first run. Then save the preferences for after the application is closed. More Technical explanation:

When it starts (on run) it will check if isSetup is false if it is it will go to the function setup(). The setup() function sets preferences and sets isSetup to true. When I quit and reopen the application is runs the setup() function again.

I know I am not supposed to copy and paste full scripts but I can't find the replicate the error without it. Here it is:

```
--AppleScript: menu bar script -- Created 2017-03-03 by Takaaki     Naganoya adapted by ----
--2017 Piyomaru Software
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
--http://piyocast.com/as/archives/4502

property aStatusItem : missing value
global theToggle
global theMenuTitle
global aTag
global aTitle
global isSetup
global usrName
global usrPass
global usrProtocol
property usrName : missing value
property usrPass : missing value
property isSetup : false
property usrProtocol : missing value
on run
    if isSetup is false then
        setup()
    else
        set theToggle to "Connect"
        set theMenuTitle to "Server Helper"
        init()

    end if
end run

on init()
    set aList to {theToggle, "Preferences", "Change Password", "",  "Quit"}
    set aStatusItem to current application's NSStatusBar's  systemStatusBar()'s statusItemWithLength:(current application's     NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    aStatusItem's setTitle:theMenuTitle
    aStatusItem's setHighlightMode:true
    aStatusItem's setMenu:(createMenu(aList) of me)
end init

on createMenu(aList)
    set aMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s init()
    set aCount to 1
    repeat with i in aList
        set j to contents of i
        if j is not equal to "" then
            set aMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:j action:"actionHandler:" keyEquivalent:"")
        else
            set aMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's separatorItem())
        end if
        (aMenuItem's setTarget:me)
        (aMenuItem's setTag:aCount)
        (aMenu's addItem:aMenuItem)
        if j is not equal to "" then
            set aCount to aCount + 1
        end if
    end repeat

    return aMenu
end createMenu

on setup()
    display dialog "                Welcome to the Server setup     Utility. 
                        To Begin click " & quote & "Continue" & quote & " below." buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2
    set theButton to the button returned of the result

    if theButton is "Continue" then
        display dialog "Please enter your " & quote & "Username" & quote & " for the Brown Server." default answer "Username" buttons {"Continue"} default button 1
        set usrName to the text returned of the result
        display dialog "Please enter your " & quote & "Password" & quote & " for the Brown Server." default answer "" buttons {"Continue"} default button 1 with hidden answer
        set usrPass to the text returned of the result
        set listDeProtocols to {"AFP", "SMB", "WebDav", "FTP"}
        set usrProtocol to (choose from list listDeProtocols with prompt "Choose Your Prefered Protocol. AFP is recomended. If AFP does not work try SMB. All others are not supported at this time")
        set isSetup to true
        postSet()
    end if
end setup
on postSet()
    if isSetup is false then
        setup()
    else
        set theToggle to "Connect"
        set theMenuTitle to "Server Helper"
        init()
    end if
end postSet

on changePref()

end changePref
on pref()
    set length1 to the length of usrPass
    set p1 to ""
    set p2 to ""
    repeat length1 times
        set p1 to "•"
        set p2 to p1 & p2
    end repeat
    display dialog "These are your following preferences. Click the " & quote & "Change" & quote & " to change.

Username: " & usrName & "
Password:  " & p2 & "

Prefered Protocol: " & usrProtocol buttons {"Back", "Change"}
    set theButton to the button returned of the result

    if theButton is "Change" then
        changePref()
    end if
end pref

on actionHandler:sender
    set aTag to tag of sender as integer
    set aTitle to title of sender as string

    if aTitle is not equal to "Quit" then
        current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s     removeStatusItem:aStatusItem
        if aTitle is "Connect" then
            set theToggle to "Disconnect"
            init()
        end if
        if aTitle is "Disconnect" then
            current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s     removeStatusItem:aStatusItem
            set theToggle to "Connect"
            init()
        end if

        if aTitle is "Preferences" then
            pref()
        end if

        if aTitle is "Change Password" then
            changePass()
        end if
    else
        current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s     removeStatusItem:aStatusItem
    end if
end actionHandler:
```

Comment: Works as it should for me. What version of OS X/macOS are you using?

Comment: High Sierra. Try Exporting as an application and see if it works.

Comment: You do realize that if you compile and or save the AppleScript script/application after its been set to different value during a run that it resets to the original value, e.g. in this example `missing value`, right?  It works for me as it should in macOS High Sierra too.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand that. But that is only if I compile or save. But I am doing neither when I export the script as an  application and open the application. The first time it opens it should ask for input but the next infinite amount of times it should display a dialog box with "A is " and then whatever you entered in the text box. To make sure we did the same I copied and pasted the script from above into a new apple script window and without pressing compile went to File>Export File Format: Application. Then opened the application.

Comment: Code is always compiled as it's being saved including when exported. If I copy and paste the code, export it as an app and run it typing in `Hello` and run it again, it displays `A is Hello` each subsequent run. If I save it again and I type anything else, it keeps asking for input until I input `Hello`. This is the expected behavior. Are you saying this is not what's happening for you?

Comment: Sorry the dummy code worked. But my original wouldn't I have edited the question to include my original script. I apologize for copy and pasting but I could not replicate the problem with a dummy script. P.S. Please recomment I can't add another comment it wants me to create a chat. Thanks!

Comment: The issue lies somewhere in the original source code from the URL in the script. After cleaning it up so it would compile and then adding a bit of code to set a property and display its value, then modify it and display again, it doesn't retain its value between runs when run as an application outside of Script Editor, but does so from within Script Editor. As a workaround, using a .plist file to store settings might be a way to get things working.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't save passwords in a plist file. I went through the script and I found that this line in the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. set `aStatusItem to current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s statusItemWithLength:(current application's NSVariableStatusItemLength)`

Comment: I just did some testing, using the original posted code, and the property value once changed from the original value is saved in human readable form in the main.scpt. So I'd imagine that the changed value of `usrPass` will be human readable too. So for security purposes I forgo the use of the variable as a property, encrypt the value and save it in a plist. Save the App as Run-only so as to avoid someone seeing the code your using to encrypt/decrypt the `usrPass` saved in the plist. Obviously all other info your trying to save in a property variable will need to be saved to the plist as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I decided to just take out the property aStatudItem and then use two buttons (connect and disconnect) instead of having a toggle. (I make the toggle by removing and readding the menu bar item with a different button. But by removing the property declaration I could only remove menu bar item by quitting so it would not have worked). What is more concerning is the password security issue.How do you suggest about encrypting a variable. Not very familiar with hashes and things like that. I will do some research tomorrow and post back here. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

---

Update: doesn't work

YES!!!! I finally found the answer. You have to remove the `property aStatusItem : missing value` from the stop of the script. This will prevent aStatusItem from being used between functions. Because of this the menu bar won't be removed when you press quit. To fix that problem at the end change `current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar()'s     removeStatusItem:aStatusItem` to `tell me to quit`. This quits the application resulting in the menu bar item being removed.

Comment: Just found out this prevents all the buttons from working.

Comment: You may wish to look at using `defaults read` and `defaults write`. This will save your information into a .plist file. Although, i agree with the other users that state it will/should work with the property as well.

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd, While `defaults` could be used in a `do shell script` _command_, nonetheless **System Events** in **AppleScript** has a **Property List Suite** and would probably be considered the default method in AppleScript for working with plist files in a use case such as this. As to the use of a `property` _variable_, if this was just plain AppleScript there wouldn't be an issue, however either the coding of the script is at issue or because this script is using scripting additions, Foundation and AppKit frameworks, one or more of these may be at issue as well.

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd, I don't have time to troubleshoot and I'd use a plist file with encrypted entries for sensitive info, e.g. user and password, in place of `property` _variables_, as tis would be faster for men then the troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok. Not sure how to encrypt though. Did some research and the main way that I have found is to change the Unicode value but that is easily decrypted. Will do more reasesrch. Thanks for help!

Comment: Can't figure out how to encrypt! :(